# How to create a simultaneous fetch XML for contacts and leads

Tags: dynamics-crm

I'm using the following XML to fetch all the contacts.

```
<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='true'>
  <entity name='contact'>
    <attribute name='fullname' />
    <attribute name='emailaddress1' />
    <order attribute='fullname' descending='false' />
    <link-entity name='listmember' from='entityid' to='contactid' visible='false' intersect='true'>
      <link-entity name='list' from='listid' to='listid' alias='aa'>
      <filter type='and'>
        <condition attribute='listname' operator='eq' value='myList' />
      </filter>
      </link-entity>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

However, I'd like the CRM also to produce the leads (preferably in the same list). Is it doable and if so, how?

Comment: Contacts and Leads are different entities in Dynamics CRM

Comment: Don't they inherit from the same daddy class? Or at least the one is a super class to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this isn't possible.

Mscrm will return zero or more records for a single entity and zero or more records from entities linked to those in a single call.

For example your fetch above gets contacts and list members linked to contacts.

You could retrieve leads linked to your contacts in a single call, but if you want all leads you will have to perform a separate call.

---

**Edit:**

"(a) two different `<entity>` section in the same `<fetch>`" - This wont work because its not valid schema.

[FetchXML Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb930489.aspx)

> entity element - used for specifying the root element for a fetch,
>   only
>                      one root entity is allowed in a given fetch, all others
>                      are dependent on this entity and are marked as
>                      link-entity

"(b) on a super class that both contacts and leads inherit from" - This wont work because as far as I know it doesn't exist. Although a single object `Entity` exists that can be used to represent all records in code, I don't believe this allows querying of multiple entities at once.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution based on either (a) two different `<entity>` section in the same `<fetch>` or (b) on a super class that both contacts and leads inherit from. Judging by your words, I can forget about it. Is that correct understood?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know what you want to do isnt possible (added a little more info to my post). Out of interest why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: I'm creating an add-in that works with marketing lists and those can be of three types: `leads`, `contacts`, `accounts`. Now I'll have to pull all marketing lists of each type (three operations). I'd like to get them as lead/contact/account-type of entity. Since I only get a name and e-mail from each, that should be sufficient to aggregate them, I figure.

Comment: I know you're trying to minimize DB round-trips, but unless you're talking about hundreds of thousands of records, it's not going to be much more work to simply aggregate the three retrieveMultiple calls into a single collection.